# Why is my $PATH (seemingly) not working when trying to use Python in my terminal?

Tags: python, python-3.x, macos, terminal

I know there are many related questions to this problem, but I have yet to come across a solution that's helped me. I'm relatively new to using the terminal, so any and all insight will be massively appreciated!

I have Python3.7 installed on my laptop (Mac M1). In my terminal, when I type

`which python3` the output is,

`/usr/bin/python3`

When I type,

`echo $PATH` the output is,

`”/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/Library/TeX/texbin:/Library/Apple/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin/python3`

Finally, when I try,

`python3 --version` the output is,

`python3: error: can't exec '/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/python3' (errno=No such file or directory)`

I'm very confused because the path in the error isn't in my $PATH.

Comment: If you `ls -l /usr/bin/python3`, is it a symbolic link to the other one?

Comment: When I try that, I get ```-rwxr-xr-x  76 root  wheel  167120 11 Aug 02:44 /usr/bin/python3```

Comment: What do you see in `hash`?  By the way, `/usr/local/bin/python3` is a file, and files do not belong in your PATH -- only folders.

Comment: Notice the link count — 76! — in the `ls -l` output. That is not a normal Python binary; that’s some Apple contraption which, apparently, tries to run the Python that comes with Xcode, which, in turn, seems to have gone AWOL. Unfortunately, I don’t understand the details of Apple’s magic, so this is a comment, not an answer...

Comment: If I look for python3 after typing ```hash```, I see ```python3=/usr/bin/python3``` (and thank you for the other info, I will tend to that as well!)

Comment: @TurePålsson I appreciate the comment nonetheless!

Comment: "I'm very confused because the path in the error isn't in my $PATH." Well, yes; if the problem were because Python wasn't found on the path, the error would be coming from the shell. This error comes **from the Python process**, which is why it a) looks totally different from the error you'd get from `this_program_is_definitely_not_installed --version`; b) has the name `python3` prepended to it. Since the error is coming from Python, we can conclude that Python **did start**; it is simply having a problem doing what it needs to do, in order to handle the `--version` argument.

Comment: I think this question likely represents a special case of a more interesting problem, that should become a canonical in the future if it doesn't already exist.

Answer (score 0):

As you have `/usr/bin` first in your path, when you just run `python3`, the shell will pick up `/usr/bin/python3`.  Now, that’s not a real Python interpreter. You can tell that from the fact that its link count is 76. That means that it is one of 76 different names for the same program! These are “shims” that Apple install in `/usr/bin`, which just hand over control to various developer tools installed as part of Xcode. That is why, when you try to run it, you get an error message talking about Xcode.

I do not fully understand how those shims work, and why the supposedly-Xcode-installed Python is not available on your system, so I will not delve further into that. (My *guess* is that `xcode-select` figures somewhere in the answer...)

However, if you *have* installed Python manually in the `/usr/local` hierarchy, it might be a good idea to fix your `PATH` variable so that `/usr/local/bin` appears before `/usr/bin`. Theat way, then you run `python3`, you get the one you installed, not the Apple one.

Comment: "You can tell that from the fact that its link count is 76." How did you determine this? Will it be the same on every system? Is there something in OP's output that evidences this claim? Anyway, how does the fact that this is a shim handing over control to another program, explain the error? For example, are you suggesting that `/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/python3` *is the path that it's trying to hand off to*, and that the program is missing from this (explicit, absolute) path?

Comment: "Theat way, then you run python3, you get the one you installed, not the Apple one." That's the thing, though: it doesn't appear that OP is getting "the Apple one", either. Or at least, that one should be able to handle starting up with the `--version` option, yeah?

Comment: @KarlKnechtel the link count of 76 came from a suggested command to test out. I think I likely exacerbated my own problem with all the fiddling I've been doing... "The Apple one" should definitely have worked... but all the comments here have been helpful!

Comment: I also managed to finally get it to work! I changed $PATH to ```/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin``` and now ```python3 --version``` outputs ```Python 3.7.0``` -- thank you all!

Comment: @KarlKnechtel The link count is in the `ls -l` output in a comment. No, it won’t be the same on every system, because the number of shims installed will vary (though it is 76 on my M1 macbook with macOs Ventura, too). And yes, I’m suggesting that the binary that the shim is trying to run is missing.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to the information provided, I found a solution that works. The following PATH did the trick:

`/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin`

Comment: Any particular reason you are using the versioned binary?